# jqgrid descending date sort not working properly

Tags: date, sorting, jqgrid

Using jqgrid 3.7.2, C#, Asp.Net
Case: Data coming from sql server in backend to datatable on server side, contains date column e.g.

On load date column has following:

2013-09-15 20:54:03.047

2013-09-15 20:54:03.050

2013-09-15 20:54:03.053

2013-09-15 20:54:11.360

Expected desc date column sort should be:

2013-09-15 20:54:11.360

2013-09-15 20:54:03.053

2013-09-15 20:54:03.050

2013-09-15 20:54:03.047

**But getting:**

2013-09-15 20:54:11.360

2013-09-15 20:54:03.047

2013-09-15 20:54:03.050

2013-09-15 20:54:03.053

Seems like descending sort is only sorting upto minutes and not milliseconds.

Using following code:

colModel: [{ name: 'LoggedAt', index: 'LoggedAt', width: 60, title: false, sortable: true}],
sortname: 'LoggedAt',
sortorder: 'DESC'

Please suggest.

Comment: What date format is in SQL Server and what date format you are using in c#. You may need to use datetime2 in SQL and datetime object in c# for this model. I assume you can view seconds on the output from json so probably best is to create a breakpoint before your filter and sort and one after it then compare both results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: I am using DataGrid for binding and default DataGrid Date format is "d". Changed the format to "{0:MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss:fff tt}" and now jqgrid sorting is working properly

Answer (score 0):

What is the actual query hitting the sql server?  (You can either print the query variable to the php log, or use the SQL Server profiler to determine it.   Then you can test the query in a query window to see what order the data is coming back from the SQL Server.

Comment: query looks like:

exec GetLog 20167
(20167 is job id)

I think the problem is . before milliseconds in the date.

Comment: Actually the problem is that I need to sort up to milliseconds and tried several things but nothing looks good. Maybe missing on something.